# Show that on the parabola $y = x^2 $, from point $A(1,1)$ to the point $B(x,y)$, that $\Delta y/\Delta x = x + 1$ (if $\Delta x \ne 0$)??

Tags: calculus

I can obviously show that $\Delta y / \Delta x = 2x + \Delta x$ but I have been pulling my hair to show that it equals $x + 1$.  Any pointers?

*(From Thomas' Calculus & Analytic Geometry, 4th Ed. (1969) Article 1.3 No.15)*

**Update**:  Here's my proposed answer...

Given points $A(1,1)$ and $B(x,y)$, and $ y = x^2 $

then $\Delta x = x - 1$ and $\Delta y = y - 1$

$$
\begin{align}
y - \Delta y &= (x - \Delta x) ^ 2 \cr
y - \Delta y &= x^2 - 2x \cdot \Delta x + (\Delta x)^2 \cr\cr
{\rm subtracting\ } y &= x^2 {\rm\ gives} \cr\cr
- \Delta y &= -2x \cdot \Delta x + (\Delta x)^2 \cr\cr
- \frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x} &= -2x + \Delta x \cr\cr
\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x} &= 2x - \Delta x \cr\cr
\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x} &= 2x - (x - 1) \cr\cr
\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x} &= x + 1 \cr
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to make a joke that both of you are true if 
$$2x+\Delta x=x+1$$

But wait a minute. Both of you are really right. You just need to remove confusion by considering more index details:

$$2x_A+\Delta x = x_B+1$$

It is true as
$$\Delta x = x_B-x_A~,~~~~~~~x_A=1$$

So you are talking about two different $x$.

Comment: You got me at least looking in the right direction.  Thank you.